# Saving hashed string in a variable

Tags: bash, perl, encryption, command-substitution, hashsum

I need to hash a string with SHA-512 algoithm. I have a salt also.

I'm trying in the script this:

```
inputHash=$( perl -e 'print crypt("${array[3]}","\${pass[0]}\$${pass[1]}\$") . "\n"' )
```

Where array[3] is the password,
pass[0] is the hash algorithm (6)
and pass[1] is the salt.

What am I doing wrong? Any other ways to do the SHA512 in the shell script?

Thanks you in advance!

**Edit:** The variable inputHash is empty

Comment: Can you describe the symptoms you're seeing with the current solution (in an [edit] to the question)? I suspect the strong outer quotes are leading to empty values to the crypt() function.

Answer (score 4):

You don't actually explain this, but it looks like you are attempting to use a shell variable inside the Perl script. `${array[3]}` is the fourth element of the *shell array variable* `$array`. Perl has no knowledge of this, so `${array[3]}` is undefined in the Perl script.

You have two ways around it. First, and worst, you can use double quotes instead of single quotes in your Perl script so that shell variables are expanded:

```
$ array=("foo" "bar" "baz" "password")
$ pass=("sha512" "randomString")
$ perl -le "print crypt('${array[3]}','${pass[0]}' . '${pass[1]}')"
shY2thr3eF5bs
```

A far better way would be to pass the variables as arguments to your Perl script:

```
$ perl -le 'print crypt($ARGV[0],$ARGV[1])' "${array[3]}" "${pass[0]}${pass[1]}"
shY2thr3eF5bs
```

Comment: what is suposed to return this command? perl -le 'print crypt($ARGV[0],$ARGV[1])' "${array[3]}" "${pass[0]}${pass[1]}"

Comment: @areverte not sure what you mean. I am showing the exact output and the exact input. The output of both of the commands will always depend on the input. In this case, where I have set the `array` and `pass` variables as in the answer above, the result is `shY2thr3eF5bs\n`. Of course, it will only work if you actually have `${array[3]}`, `${pass[0]}` and `${pass[1]}` defined. Since you don't show us where you set those variables in your question, I am assuming you know what to do with them.

Comment: I'm trying to hash a password. Using the code above I get shWBODbAyBUvM and the correct output is 0f23d2f577126984fabb23326dc270dad8eedcbb270c2c56b6e790713b33c1ef636284d55300a535ac359b57f127c4c764bc9bfc57a323da9c0ead9453071549

Comment: @areverte I don't know about that. I am simply showing you how to run the command _you_ were trying to run. Whether or not that is the command you want is something only you can know. I can tell you that perl's `crypt()` function doesn't actually take the hashing algortihm as input, but I assumed you knew that already since you were using it. I now suspect you might be looking for something like `printf 'string' | sha512sum` but, again, I can't know since you aren't actually telling us anything other than the command you were trying. You might want to open a new question instead.